# Can we use .so files on windows?

Tags: c++, dll, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

I have a requirement to create and link libraries dynamically for my c++ codebase on windows and linux platform.
I know DLL format is for windows and .so is for linux platform.
But I read .so can be linked on windows platform also.
My question is, can I create a common dynamic libraries (.so) to run my application on windows and linux? If yes, How?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using both .so and .dll on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233766/using-both-so-and-dll-on-windows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion a better solution would be to generate either *so or *dll depending on for what platform the SW is built. Then you link with the native tools. Recommend to read about `cmake`

Comment: Thanks a lot for prompt reply. :)